# environment vs enclosure in R

Tags: r

I am confused about the envir and enclos arguments of eval().

```
  enclos: ...
          Specifies the enclosure, i.e., where R looks for objects not
          found in ‘envir’.  ...
```

Is the enclosure argument just closure defined below?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)

If enclos is used when things are not found in envir, why not just combine whatever in enclos into envir as a single argument envir?

Comment: I think "enclosure != closure"; while they may be very similar, *closure* (to me) suggests in/around a function, whereas my interpretation of `enclos=` here is effectively `envir2=` (i.e., not tied to a function). I've never thought about this argument, tbh, and have a hard time imagining a time when it would be strictly necessary.

Comment: The help doc's example of `eval(x, data, parent.frame())` is interesting to me, but ... again, haven't had the need for it, so I don't know for certain. This use suggests a form of "Inception" (movie) or recursion of environment references.

Answer (score 3):

> Is the enclosure argument just closure defined below?

No, they’re distinct concepts, this has nothing to do with closures.

Environments have parent environments. If a name isn’t found in a given environment, it’s looked up in its parent environment, and so on, until the last environment without a parent is reached. This happens *everywhere* in R code when a name is looked up. That’s why the following works:

```
x = 1

f = function (y) x + y

f(2) # = 3
```

Executing `f` creates an environment (a “stack frame”) the parent of which is is the global environment. Looking up `x` inside `f` will find `x` in the parent environment.

When you pass an environment to `eval`’s `envir` argument, the expression is evaluated in that environment, and the same happens:

```
x = 1

# `environment()` = the *current* environment.
e = new.env(parent = environment())
e$y = 2

eval(quote(x + y), envir = e) # = 3
```

However, `eval` also supports passing non-environment arguments in `eval`. E.g. lists (or `data.frame`s). But lists don’t have the concept of a “parent environment”, so the following wouldn’t work:

```
x = 1

lst = list(y = 2)

eval(quote(x + y), envir = lst)
```

… because `x` isn’t found inside `lst`. But in fact this *does* work; and the reason is `enclos`: if you pass something other than an environment to `eval`, the `enclos` arguments acts in stead of a parent environment of `envir` (if you pass an environment in `envir`, `enclos` is unneeded and will be ignored). In the above I didn’t need to specify `enclos` since the argument defaults to the calling environment. I could also set it to something else entirely:

```
x = 1 # This variable is *not used* below!

e = new.env()
e$x = 3
lst = list(y = 2)

eval(quote(x + y), envir = lst, enclos = e) #  = 5
```